# Vehicle plugin without control

Tags: gazebo-plugin

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi

I have designed [simple model of car](http://code.google.com/p/lego-nxt-car-like/source/browse/trunk/car_like_simulation/car_like.urdf.xacro) with ackermann steering. Also I have designed [ackermann plugin](http://code.google.com/p/lego-nxt-car-like/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fackermann_plugin_gazebo) to control the model. However, the model and plugin don't work in the new version Gazebo (1.3).
I tried to find a similar model of car for the newest version Gazebo.
I have found model of [car](http://gazebosim.org/models/utility_cart/) what I was looking for.
However, I was surprised that vehicle plugin for this car model don't contain subscriber of control topic. In fact, there is subscriber on cmd_vel topic, but it is empty.

```
void VehiclePlugin::OnVelMsg(ConstPosePtr &/*_msg*/)
{
}
```

There are plans to further develop the plugin?

PS. I could develop the plugin by myself. But I would like know if somebody are doing this work too.

Best Regards,
Alex

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1170/vehicle-plugin-without-control/) by [Alex Buyval](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/182/alex-buyval/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 31 on 2013-02-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You should go ahead and develop this plugin further. Thanks for asking.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-02-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0